# How to convert a base64 string into jpeg

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I get a a base64 string which I need to convert into a .jpg picture for my iPhone app. Here is my code:

```
        Services * serv = [[Services alloc] init];
        NSData * dataToWrite = [serv base64DataFromString:item.Photo];

        UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageWithData:dataToWrite];
```

I am probably missing something here. Any ideas?
After i convert the string to NSData and try to show it in a uiimage view  all i get is a black picture frame, I get no errors

Comment: What's the problem with what you have?  Be specific.

Comment: what error/issue are you htting?

Comment: What's the problem? Exceptions? What is `item.Photo`?. How does `serv` do Base64 encoding? Please put some more effort in your question.

Comment: Note that UIImage is not the same thing as jpeg or png

Comment: After i convert the string to NSData and try to show it in a uiimageview  all i get is a black picture frame, I get no errors, item.photo is a nsstring that holds the base64 string

Comment: Are you sure that the original image was converted to base64 string correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you don´t actually send the dataToWrite to the `imageWithData` method.
Do this instead:

```
Services * serv = [[Services alloc] init];
NSData * dataToWrite = [serv base64DataFromString:item.Photo];
UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageWithData:dataToWrite];
```

Comment: sorry that was a editing error on my part that's not the problem

Comment: No problem. I am wondering what the `item.Photo` is. Can you provide the line where you allocate item?

Comment: see my question-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443841/touches-to-generate-some-star-or-kiss-image-in-the-touch-location-area-in-iphone for some idea given